# Динамическое добавление элементов

Tags: android

Вообщем требуется динамически выводить элементы для ввода на экран. Допустим есть файл (ну что угодно), в котором написано что у нас должно быть 2 поля для ввода, 3 лист бокса, и 2 лейбела. Вот как их добавлять на экран динамически? В дальнейшем требуется возможность получения данных из файлах и их отправки. Число элементов не ограничено, все зависит от исходнных данных полученных для их создания.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i< text.lines; i++)
{
    if(line[i].Contains("Button")
    {
        Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        b.... // Назначаем параметры
        ...
        _linearLayout.Children.Add(b);
    }
    else if(line[i].Contains("Gallery"){
        ...
        _linearLayout.Children.Add(...);
    }
}
```

Что сложного то?

Comment: Ну а данные с них то как получать?) Баттонов может быть 10 допустим все будут иметь имя b?

Comment: На уровне активити сделайте массив (или другую структуру), и пихайте в нее очередной b. Учите Java и андройдовский java.util